# Pass only certain events to parent node in javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

If I have two absolutely positioned elements and I want to ignore events on the upper one so that they're handled by the lower, I can set the upper's style to `pointer-events: none`. Is there a way to only capture some events (mousedown, mouseup) and pass others through (mouse wheel)?

Here's an example with an SVG and a div:

https://jsfiddle.net/pkerpedjiev/6b54psq2/1/

I would like to be able to click on the svg and fire the `click` event. At the same time, I would like to scroll on the svg and fire the `div wheel.zoom` event. Is this possible?

HTML

```
  <body>
    <div class="div">
    </div>
    <svg width=400 height=200>
    </svg>
  </body>
  <script>

  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.4.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

JS

```
d3.select("svg")
.on('click', function(d) { console.log('svg click'); })

d3.select('.div')
.on('wheel.zoom', function(d) { console.log('div mouse wheel')})
```

CSS

```
.div {

  position: absolute,
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background: yellow;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: You want something like that : https://jsfiddle.net/j63xkoj9/ ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! But is it possible to do that while keeping the event handler on the div rather than placing it on the body?

Comment: You can use `dispatch` on selection inside svg event trigger like
`.on('wheel.zoom', function(d) { d3.select('.div').dispatch('wheelInsideSvg') })` 
 But I'm not familiar with d3 to know how to do it with real `wheel.zoom`

Comment: @MirkoVukušić: Thanks for the suggestion. That may work, but what if I have two different divs below the SVG? Then I would need to keep track of the mouse position and dispatch the event to the appropriate div.